# GeoTools TileServer implementation for Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, geotools

GeoTools TileServer has implementations for OSM and Bing.

Is there one for Google Maps?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [tile-client module](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/tree/master/modules/extension/tile-client/src/main/java/org/geotools/tile/impl) you can see the code for OSM and Bing. This is where you can add a Google implementation if you need. You can probably copy and modify the Bing one quite easily, assuming that Google's ToS allow this sort of client (I seem to recall they didn't use to).